# Is it a violation of NEC code to install a receptacle horizontally and 3/4" from face of a stud?

Tags: electrical, wiring, framing, nec

A wall has been framed out to mount a touch screen computer monitor. Once the 1/4" drywall is installed, the monitor will be placed into this cavity and plugged into said receptacle.

**Question**

Does the receptacle shown in the pictures below meet NEC code? If not, whats is the proper way to install the receptacle in recessed stud framing?

[image: Side view of Recepatcle]

[image: Overhead view of receptacle]

Comment: How will the monitor be mounted into the bay? The main concern here is being able to get at the junction box for later servicing

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It will be mounted with a VESA slide on mount. Similar to this one: https://www.amazon.com/VideoSecu-Monitor-Screen-Maximum-Loading/dp/B000VKCIJU/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1469381200&sr=8-10&keywords=monitor+mount+slide

Comment: Might be worth using a metal box in this situation.  Then you don't have to worry as much about a nail, screw, or drill bit puncturing the box.

Answer (score 2):

Provided the mount and cables allow the monitor to be readily removed to gain access to the box, this should not be a Code issue -- the basic requirement is that all junction boxes be readily accessible (i.e. you shouldn't have to tear apart the building to find 'em).

Comment: What about the side of the receptacle only being 3/4" from the face of the stud. There will be drywall over that gap, but is that ok and within code?

Comment: @RyanLazuka -- that's not an issue as long as the box is mounted securely and there's room to get the wire in.

Comment: Code requires that when drilling studs that a wire needs to be 1 1/4" from the face of a stud where a potential for a nail to be driven into it. When it is less than that, a nail plate is placed over the wire to protect it. It may not be a code item for a box in the same situation? Just asking...

Comment: @Jack -- boxes are assumed to be not-accidentally-nailable-through in the Code I suspect, otherwise you'd have Code problems with very deep boxes in 2x4 walls for the same reason even though you aren't quite out of physical space in the wall cavity

Comment: Ahhh good point....

Comment: There's also some presumption that you can see an outlet there and thus infer that drilling there would be a bad idea. Not that some people wouldn't, but those same people will determinedly drill right through steel plates and boxes, so...

Comment: Probably not a code issue per se, but my local inspector asked me to put nail plates behind deep boxes in 2x4 walls. Wouldn't hurt to put one over this box, or like mentioned, change it to metal, for peace of mind.